# Finding a subset of `n` distinct vectors with minimum distance of `d`

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a set of vectors `V` (say a 64 dimension vector like `[1,2,...64]`). From vector set `V`, I want to find a subset of `n` (`n` is any number > 0) distinct vectors, `V1`, where

1. any two vectors in subset `V1` has a minimum distance of `d` and also;
2. for any element `w` in vector set `V`, there exists an element `w'` in subset `V1` that can reach `w` with a distance that is less than `d`.

What would be an effective algorithm to determine one subset of `n` distinct vectors, where the value of `n` is minimum?

The distance can either be Euclidean Distance or Cosine Similarity (of course there is no mixture of both).

Comment: What do you mean by minimum possible n?

Comment: @joostblack The value of n with minimum value, no?

Comment: Should you ask for maximum n instead? Since any set with 1 element satisfies the condition.

Comment: @user202729 but if there exists a vector that is with distance >1 then the 1 element, then it wouldn't be satisfied, right?

Comment: @joostblack user202729 is right

Comment: You ask "any two vectors in V1...", but if there's no **two** vectors then it would be trivially satisfied.

Comment: @user202729 thanks for pointing that out, I added the constraint ` also there always exists an element in subset V1 can that can reach an element of V with distance that is < d`

Comment: Some terminology which should help you to research more: any maximal independent set would satisfy the condition, but to be precise you need any minimum vertex cover which is also independent. Although both maximum independent set and minimum vertex cover is NP-complete, this is the Euclidean space so it might have an easier solution -- but it seems to be no easier than the general maximum independent set problem on ~64 vertices.

Comment: Perhaps a heuristic to get a good approximate solution is to use [vector quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_quantization), but with a variation to _not_ reflect the data density in the codebook. Many years ago, I did something like that based on Neural Gas with regularization; need to dig it up if there is interest.

Comment: In other words, you want a set of vectors that has some minimum distance between them and covers the entire "area", like for cellphone masts?

Comment: @tobias_k yes, that's the gist

Comment: Usually (k-means, k-medians), we are interested in `v1` being a new set of vectors (not necessarily members of `v`). One exception that I'm aware of is [k-medoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids). But it's not a perfect fit for your question, just an area to investigate. Other areas of interest include hierarchical clustering.

Answer (score 2):

Let's think of your problem this way: You have a set of *balls* in 64-dimension space each with radius d, representing the space around each of your input vectors. (Note, I'm assuming that by "distance" you mean [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)).

Now, you want to find the smallest subset of balls that will *cover* each of your original points, meaning that you need each point to be inside at least one ball in the subset, with the additional restriction that the balls in the cover must have centers also distance d apart.

Without this additional restriction, you have an instance of a hard but well-studied one called [Geometric set cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_set_cover_problem), which in turn is a special case of the more famous [Set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). It *seems* intuitively that the additional restriction makes the problem harder, but I don't have a proof for that.

The bad news is, the (geometric) set cover problem is NP-hard, meaning that you won't be able to quickly find the exact minimum if there may be many points in the original set.

The good news is, there are good algorithms that find *approximate* solutions, which will give you a set which isn't necessarily as small as possible, but which is close to the smallest possible.

Here is Python code for a simple greedy algorithm which will not always find a minimum-size cover, but will always return a valid one:

```
def greedy(V, d):
    cover = set()
    uncovered = set(V)
    # invariant: all(distance(x,y) > d for x in cover for y in uncovered)
    while uncovered:
        x = uncovered.pop()
        cover.add(x)
        uncovered = {y for y in uncovered if distance(x,y) > d}
```

Note, you could make this greedy solution a little better by replacing the `uncovered.pop()` call with a smarter choice, for example choosing a vector which would "cover" the most number of remaining points.

Comment: Thanks, I did mean Euclidean Distance, but if I change the distance metrics to say cosine similarity, will it make a difference?

Comment: @william007 The distance measure won't make a difference for the solutions I know of (which are mostly just based on set cover), but there are probably some tricks that rely on having a distance metric (which Cosine similarity is not).

Comment: but the Set cover or vertex cover solution is necessary but not sufficient: not only do we want each point in `v` to be reachable by at least one point in `v1` with a distance `< r`, but also we want all points in `v1` to be mutually farther than `r`.

Comment: @PierreD you're right, I missed the importance of that restriction. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't think the choice of the distance meassure is important, as long as it is a metric.

Comment: @wildplasser yes, but the OP also mentioned cosine similarity, which doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality and hence not a metric.

Comment: it is very fast, but by comparing the solutions found against the brute-force version I proposed, often sub-optimal (no surprise for a greedy algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

First, we can derive an undirected graph where vertices are the vectors of `v` and edges are the pairs of points that are no farther apart than `r`. This doesn't require the distances to be a proper metric: it doesn't have to satisfy the triangle inequality, only that it is symmetrical (`dist(a,b) == dist(b,a)`) and that it is 0 iff two points are equal.

After that step, we can forget about the distances altogether and focus entirely on partitioning the graph.  As others have noted, that partition is a [Vertex Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) problem. However, it has a twist: we require all the vertices in the cover to be disjoint (i.e.: no vectors in `v1` can be within distance `r` of each other).

To obtain the graph, we can use the efficient [`KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) to compute just once the nearest-neighbor structure. In particular, we'll use `kd.sparse_distance_matrix(kd, r)` to obtain all pairs of points separated by `r` or less:

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

def get_graph(v, r):
    kd = KDTree(v)
    sm = kd.sparse_distance_matrix(kd, r)
    graph = {i: {i} for i, _ in sm.keys()}
    for i, j in sm.keys():
        graph[i] |= {j}
    return graph
```

(note: `.sparse_distance_matrix()` has a parameter `p` if we want other distances than Euclidean).

The partitioning of the graph can be done in various ways. @DanR shows a greedy approach that is very fast, but often suboptimal in the size of `v1` that it finds.

The following shows instead a brute-force approach that **is guaranteed to find a minimal solution if there is one**. It is adequate for relatively small number of vectors and can provide a ground-truth for the optimal solution, when researching other heuristics.

To speed up the combinatorial search, we first observe that often some points are not within distance `r` of any other (i.e. the graph found above doesn't represent all the points of `v`). We can leave those other points aside, since they will necessarily be part of `v1` but don't interfere with the rest of the search (below, we call them "singletons"). Second, we cut unpromising "leads" (prefixes in the combinatorial expansion) if they are not fully disjoint.  This speeds up considerably the full search, by cutting down entire swathes of search space. If no prefix is cut, the full search is time-exponential.

What is the speed of this?  It depends on the distribution of the `v` vectors and (strongly) on the distance `r`. In fact, it depends on the number of clusters found. To give an idea, with `v` 20 vectors picked in uniform in 2D, I observe roughly 30ms. For 40 vectors, typically around 100ms, but it can jump to over 2 seconds for certain values of `r`.

We implement a variation of [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) that has a `check` function to cut down unpromising prefixes:

```
from itertools import combinations

def _okall(tup, *args, **kwargs):
    return True

def combinations_all(iterable, n0=1, n1=None, check=None, *args, **kwargs):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if n0 > n:
        return
    n1 = n if n1 is None else n1
    check = _okall if check is None else check
    
    if n0 < 1:
        yield ()
        n0 = 1
    seed = list(combinations(range(n), n0-1))
    for r in range(n0, n1+1):
        prev_seed = seed
        seed = []
        for prefix in prev_seed:
            for j in range(max(prefix, default=-1)+1, n):
                indices = prefix + (j,)
                tup = tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
                if check(tup, *args, **kwargs):
                    seed.append(indices)
                    yield tup
```

Example:

```
# list all combinations of [0,1,2,3] (of all sizes), excluding those starting
# by (0,1)

>>> list(combinations_all(range(4), check=lambda tup: tup[:2] != (0,1)))
[(0,),
 (1,),
 (2,),
 (3,),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 3),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (2, 3),
 (0, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 3)]
```

Now, we use that to find the minimal disjoint cover and return the indices of `v1`:

```
def check(tup, graph):
    # refuses tup if any one is within reach of another
    # optimization: tup[:-1] has already passed this test, so just check the last one
    if len(tup) < 2:
        return True
    reach_of_last = graph[tup[-1]]
    prefix = set(tup[:-1])
    return prefix.isdisjoint(reach_of_last)

def brute_vq(v, r):
    n = v.shape[0]
    graph = get_graph(v, r)
    to_part = set(graph)
    singletons = set(range(n)).difference(to_part)
    if not to_part:
        return sorted(singletons)
    for tup in combinations_all(to_part, check=check, graph=graph):
        # here tup are indices that are far apart enough (guaranteed disjoint in reach)
        # check if they fully cover to_part
        cover = {j for i in tup for j in graph[i]}
        if cover == to_part:
            v1_idx = sorted(singletons.union(tup))
            return v1_idx
```

**Examples**:

```
v = np.random.uniform(size=(20, 2))
r_s = [[0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5]]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(r_s), ncols=len(r_s[0]),
                         figsize=(12,12), sharex=True, sharey=True)
for r, ax in zip(np.ravel(r_s), np.ravel(axes)):
    idx = brute_vq(v, r)
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.scatter(v[:, 0], v[:, 1])
    for i, p in enumerate(v):
        ax.text(*p, str(i))
    for i in idx:
        circ = plt.Circle(v[i], radius=r, color='g', fill=False)
        ax.add_patch(circ)
plt.show();
```

[image]

Comment: Did you read the question? Th OP wants to find a **single** subset. It is not about clustering.

Comment: In the above, `idx` is the list of indices of vectors of `v` to make `v1`. In VQ terms (and clustering), such a solution `v1` is called codebook or prototypes. Each picture shows the solution for a given value of `r`. It plots one green circle per such prototype (centered on it and of radius `r`), as well as the vectors of `v` as blue dots, to verify visually the solution.

Answer (score -2):

My 5c:

---

Create a distance matrix (this is an O*O operation, obviously):

```
  A B C D | min,max
A 0 3 2 1 | 1,3
B 3 0 5 4 | 3,5
C 2 5 0 6 | 2,6
D 1 4 6 0 | 1,6 # note: D-C violates the triangle inequality
```

Distance matrix, relabelled:

```
  A D B C | min,max
A 0 1 3 2 | 1,3
D 1 0 4 6 | 1,6
B 3 4 0 5 | 3,5
C 2 6 5 0 | 2,6
```

Now, per row (or column) take tha max() of the min() (or the min() of the max()...)
With a distance of 3, the NW-part is fully connected and the rest is still partially connected
(with d=4, B would enter the subset, too)

```
  A D | B C | min,max
A 0 1 | 3 2 | 1,3
D 1 0 | 4 6 | 1,6
  ----+ ----------
B 3 4 | 0 5 | 3,5
C 2 6 | 5 0 | 2,6
```

Comment: I don't follow your implied algorithm. What are the vectors of `v1`?

Comment: also, the numerical distances themselves are irrelevant. Either a pair of point is closer than `r`, or farther away than `r`. With `kd = KDTree(v)`, then `kd.sparse_distance_matrix(kd, r)` is a very efficient way of finding all pairs of points closer to each other than `r`. Then it's just a graph cover question with a twist: mutual exclusion among the cover.

Comment: I read it, several times too. Still don't see what you are trying to show.

Comment: You could see that in this case a MAX(min()) of three will isolate the minimally connected subset. I moved it to the upper-left corner for ease of reading.

Comment: are you suggesting you've just proved that P=NP?...

Comment: No. Just that the problem is ill-defined. And a counter question: can you invent a problem whre the method does *not* work?

Comment: Respectfully, I don't think the suggested approach solves the OP question at all. All vectors in `v1` must be at least `d` apart from each other. All vectors in `v` must be within `d` of some vector in `v1`. Finding a minimal set of vectors `v1` that satisfies these conditions is NP-hard. If you are suggesting in your example that `{A,D}` is the solution for `v1`, then that doesn't work because they are closer to each other than any other point in `v`. That's the opposite to what the OP wants.